# I can not run C-OpenWire client for ActiveMQ after compilation

Tags: c, ubuntu, activemq-classic

I'm trying to develop client in C for ActiveMQ using OpenWire and after compiling example [main](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/sandbox/openwire-c/src/examples/main.c) for OpenWire ActiveMQ on Ubuntu, when I try to run it I get this error:

```
bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I've tried it on both ubuntu 32 and 46 bit but it didn't work

Any Ideas?

Is there any other C alternative then OpenWire?

Comment: *How* did you build your program? What flags did you use for the compiler and linker? Did you build it for 32 or 64 bit targets?

Comment: I tried both: gcc  test -c main.c and gcc  test -c main.c -m32

Comment: now I'm just trying with 32bit target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `-c` flag, as it tells `gcc` to generate an *object* file and not an executable file.

Remove the `-c` flag:

```
gcc main.c -o test
```

Comment: for long time i didn't work with C ;) I forgot to link other resources but when I did it i got those errors: